# Do I pay sales tax exporting the bike

Tags: united-states, sales-tax, florida

We live in The Netherlands (Europe), we are Dutch. We are now buying a motorcycle in Florida, but are going to pick it up in July and then leave the state, since we're making a roadtrip. After 2 months we're going to export the bike to the Netherlands out of New York or Los Angelis.
Can we get our salestax (VAT) back and how and when?

Comment: (based on very little knowledge): You buy and use it, so I assume no, also since it's used you're not paying for import. customs fees and taxes are there to offset sales tax. Since you're likely paying far more VAT in the netherlands (20 ish percent ?) than florida (6 ish percent ?), you should come out ahead.

Comment: @xyious [Please do not answer questions in the comments](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/10997).

Comment: My comment wouldn't hold up to the standards I would put on an answer. It's just conjecture that I haven't verified. It's just a comment on how I think things likely are.

Comment: @xyious Please see the meta post I linked to. If you aren’t sure of your answer, it is even more important that it is posted as an answer, so users that do know more about it than you can edit it, comment on it, or downvote it, if necessary.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but on departure from the USA there is not a refund for sales' tax paid during your visit.  Perhaps I mis-understood the question.